# Professional way to make Isometric 3D Tilemaps for an ARPG in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, 3d, isometric

I'm was working on a top-down ARPG and now I'd like to switch to **3D Isometric**.

I know that I can **place prefabs on Unity's tilemaps**, and also have an X-Z grid, etc, but are they designed to **handle whole maps of 3D Tile GameObjects/Meshes?**

If yes, could you link some resources on how to do it well?

If not, what is the **professional way of making 3D maps for isometric games?**

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How have you tried using the prefab approach that you describe? Where specifically are you finding that method falling short of what you need?

Comment: Not yet, I'm not at that stage sadly, so I just started to think about it during my "free time" :D But I will.

Comment: @DMGregory I finally had time the test this approach. I think this isn't the intended use. Placing 3D objects on the grid is impossibly by default. It's only possible with the "2D extras" package's RuleTile feature but I think it's intended for i.e. extra behaviour scripts to be placed on the tile. Everything is still based around sprites and I have to modify the package to make it a bit more suitable for 3D but it would be still hacky/clunky. So the question still stands :(

Comment: Can you clarify what makes placing 3D objects on the grid "impossible"? That's not a problem I've ever observed in Unity, where I usually just CTRL-drag to snap to grid-sized increments. Can you try editing your question to walk us through your current workflow and where it's giving you trouble?

Comment: What I was talking about is placing them in Unity's Tilemaps' Palette. 
Yes, I can snap game objects to the grid, but then I still don't have a tilemap system I can use: I still would have to implement a framework so I can get tile data from a specific position, generate levels, etc. And that's my last resort if there isn't a faster solution. :\

Comment: Try showing us your workflow for placing objects in the tilemap palette. Folks may be able to suggest improvements for that step if that's the one giving you the most trouble.

Comment: The workflow is just: I start dragging a prefab from the "project explorer" to the Tile Palette, just as I did with Sprites previously. Nothing happens, so I guess it only accept tiles and sprites (because a tile is instantly created from sprites upon adding them to the palette).

Comment: You just need to rotate your sprite around x-axis by 90 degrees, then you get tiles in 3D world.

Comment: What? But I'm no longer using sprites. I'm using 3D meshes and I want to make a tilemap from them. :| Or maybe I've misunderstood you.